# Does a Roth 401(k) rolled into a Roth IRA count toward the annual contribution limit?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, rollover, roth-401k

I am trying to max out my Roth IRA for the 2015 tax year, and am wondering if Roth 401(k) rollovers count as a contribution.

Roth 401(k)'s are not offered by many employers, so I couldn't find much literature on it (or even anything on the IRS website).  This [article](http://finance.zacks.com/rollover-roth-ira-count-toward-annual-contribution-5036.html) from Zacks, like many others, explains that traditional 401(k)/IRA rollovers do not count towards contribution limits, but fail to mention anything about Roth 401(k)'s.

I would hope they don't count towards the limit, but am not sure because they are Roth funds.

Answer (score 6):

Rollovers do not count as contributions. It doesn't matter if they're Roth or not.